# How can I select a single photo from a photo burst using Photos.app on macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, photos.app

I have a few photo bursts in Photos.app version 5 (macOS Catalina), and Photos.app identifies them as bursts, but I cannot find any tool in the interface to select one picture in the burst or even to view them all. I don't remember if the bursts were taken with my iPhone or with a Sony a6000, and surprisingly, it does not tell in the info of the photos.

[image]

UPDATE:

Also, there is no `Make Selection...` button when I open the photo burst that appears, as was suggested in an answer below, or as I have seen in some tutorials. I don't know if this is caused my something particular with my pictures or if Photos.app version 5 is different.

[image]

Comment: for what it's worth i'm having this problem too, on multiple bursts.  no "Make a Selection" button appears.  i've selected photos from bursts before on the Mac, and i'm fairly certain i've done it in Photos in Catalina, so i'm not sure why this is broken suddenly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change to your 'Library' (previously known as 'Photos') to reveal the "Make a Selection…" button. The button is missing with 'Imports' and maybe other lists of photos.

Comment: You could add to your answer that the 'Selection' button is available when selecting a burst in the Bursts media type album. It is not available in a burst in a user created Album (& probably a Smart Album too).

Comment: Update: if you're viewing in an album, you need to right click the photo and click "Show in All Photos". Now enlarge the photo (by clicking it or pressing Spacebar). Then the "Make a Selection" button will appear on the top left of the photo.

Answer (score 0):

Double click on it, click "Make a Selection..." on the top left corner, and you'll get an interface for that.

Comment: That's what I saw on a tutorial from 2017, but I don't have the `Make Selection...` button at the top left. :-/

Answer (score -3):

Mac seems to be made not to provide support for burst photos. There is huge difficulty transporting burst photos from iphone to mac and mac has bugs to display which scenes are selected and which are not.

My suggestion is to ABANDON using burst photos completely, until Apple thinks it’s worthwhile to fix all the bugs. You can use live photos if you want to catch a motion